# Perl CGI redirect after authentication

Tags: javascript, perl, redirect, cgi

I know its a basic question and it is been asked for several times but i was not able to understand it.

I was using a html webpage with some input fields and submit button when the submit button is pressed the post is done through XMLHttpRequest and CGI script is called. In cgi script the authentication is checked with the value in the file of server.

The problem is that if the authenication is false i want to redirect the browser to the xmltest.shtml for this i have written in the CGI:

```
 if($isauthenticated == 0)
   {
     print "Location: http://xmltest.shtml\n\n";
     }
```

But when this cgi is called in return the get is called with the xmltest.shtml page but the browser is not redirected.

It means that if I check in the Firebug console the get request is seen by me for the xmltest.shtml but the browser page is not redirected to the xmltest.shtml it remains to the same page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cause the page to redirect that way. When you use XMLHttpRequest, you are sending the redirect header *to the XMLHttpRequest client*, which runs in the background. You will successfully redirect that client, but it will not affect the page on the screen.

If you want to redirect the actual browser page in response to an XMLHttpRequest session, you will need to write some JavaScript to capture the error condition and redirect the browser by updating the value of `document.location.href`.

If you're using an AJAX framework like jQuery, there is an [error callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  available in the `ajax` method which will get executed if your failed request returns an HTTP 403 or similar.

Comment: yeah i have done the same thing i am sending the redirect location in the response of the xmlhttprequest and then using javascript fetching the value and redirecting using 
document.location.href but i was thinking its a bad practise. Is there any good practise for the purpose of authentication and redirection

Comment: That is the correct way to do it. My only recommendation would be to use an HTTP error code (403 is good) and have the JavaScript detect that and update the URL. Sending a redirect header from the server isn't helpful here.